# Why can't I "vote up" a good answer unless I have a "reputation" of 15 or more?

Tags: support, up-votes

Why does this site have such a restrictive policy of allowing people to participate?! I find it incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Because you have to prove your worth to the community first. If just anyone could vote, it'd be trivial to massively boost spam/bot accounts.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Answer (score 10):

It's to prevent people from creating new accounts just to spam-upvote their other accounts in order to artificially boost reputation.

Getting a rep of 15 is easy, just answer a single question. That proves you're not a bot.

Comment: Although there is a legitimate case to be made for OP to be able to vote on answers to his own question.

Comment: Yes, but a new account could be made to post a question just for the other account to answer, and then to upvote the answer.

Comment: They can do that already by accepting the answer in the "dummy question".